# Obtaining actual parameter values in a Jersey ResourceFilterFactory

Tags: java, rest, authorization, jersey, jax-rs

I want to implement custom authorisation in my REST services using Jersey. This custom authorisation inspects annotations on methods as well as the actual parameters that a 
method receives.

My jax-rs annotated method looks like:

```
@GET
@Path("customers")
@Requires(Role.CustomerManager)
public Customer getCustomer(@ParseFromQueryString @CheckPermission final Customer customer) {
    // ...
}
```

The `@ParseFromQueryString` is an annotation that indicates Jersey (through an Injectable provider) to unmarshall a `Customer` from a query string. The code for that looks like:

```
public class QueryStringCustomerInjectable implements Injectable<Customer> {
  public Customer getValue() {
    final Customer customer = new Customer();
    // ... a UriInfo was injected using the @Context annotation
    // ... extract parameters from QueryString and use setters
    return customer;
  }
}
```

The `@CheckPermission` annotation indicates my custom authoriser that permissions are to be checked on a customer. Some users have access to information on some customers. Similarly, the `@Requires` annotation takes a role that the invoker should have. These are not java's security roles (Strings), rather, they are enum values.

Using Jersey's `ResourceDebuggingFilter` as a starting point, I have been able to get to the point of knowing which method will be invoked. However, I still haven't figured out how to determine which parameters will actually be used to invoke the method.

At the top of my head, I can think of two work arounds:

1. A Method interceptor using Guice + Jersey.
2. Code this logic in the `QueryStringCustomerInjectable`, but this seems a bit sloppy. It would be a class doing *too much*.

Yet, I would *really* like to do this using only Jersey / JAX-RS. I feel that I am so close!

Ideas? Pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: I still haven't found a guice-less way of doing this... So it is either using guice, or use cxf, which provides interceptors and a way to provide your own invokers.

Comment: Have you looked into AOP or just using a Servlet Filter for workaround 1?

Comment: Have you tried using a `ContainerRequestFilter` and injecting the Customer into it? I'm not sure if `@BeanParam`s are restricted to resources or if they can also be injected into filters, but I'd assume so long as the filter is not preMatch, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Filters` or `Interceptors` to handle all the information about method.
  [see Jersey Filter and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9712)

Answer (score 0):

For the Customer deserialization you could implement the javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider and register it into Jersey. Then you can inject it into your methods with @QueryParam("customer"). It's a bit more flexible since you can use it also with @BeanParam or @PathParam annotations.

Then you can use the ContainerRequestFilter. See as a reference how jersey does the Oauth1 for example [OAuth1ServerFilter](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.5.1/jersey/project/oauth1-server/xref/org/glassfish/jersey/server/oauth1/OAuth1ServerFilter.html).
The next thing you can do is to create maybe a feature which will register the newly created filter (see [Oauth1ServerFeature](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/oauth1/OAuth1ServerFeature.html) for a reference - I couldn't find the source code right now).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using your own Servlet filter e.g.

```
public class YourFilter implements Filter {
  ...
  @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    // HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    // HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    // HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    // ..... httpReq.getUserPrincipal();


    // then set what you need using ThreadLocal and use it inside your resource class

    // do not forget to call 
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response); // at the end of this method

 }
```

The last step is to register your servlet filter. This is done using web app's web.xml

It will intercept your HTTP requests before the actual code inside jersey resource is called.